# How to cleanly access deeply embeded fields in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My documents are stored in the format `sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp[].cpu-load-all.cpu[].usr`, where `timestamp` is a 30 element array, and `cpu` is a 1-64 element array.

[image]

If I grab the `timestamp` field,

```
timestampCursor = HOST_USAGE.find(
   {'sysstat.host.nodename': host}, 
   {'sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp': 1})
```

How can I then access `sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp[*].cpu-load-all.cpu[0].usr`, cleanly? Do I have to access each field by indexing each array, and so multiple iterations over each array-field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to access each field by indexing each array, and so multiple iterations over each array-field.

```
for doc in timestampCursor:
    sysstat = doc['sysstat']
    for ts in sysstat['host']['statistics']['timestamp']:
        for cpu in ts['cpu-load-all']['cpu']:
            usr = cpu['usr']
            # Now, sum or average the 'usr' values, or whatever
            # you intend to do.
```

Alternatively, to aggregate the data server-side, you can use $unwind with $sum or $average or some other grouping operation with the MongoDB Aggregation Framework.

```
HOST_USAGE.aggregate([{
    '$match': {'sysstat.host.nodename': 1}
}, {
    # Rename the field for brevity.
    '$project': {'ts': '$sysstat.host.statistics.timestamp'}
}, {
    '$unwind': '$ts'
}, {
    '$unwind': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu'
}, {
    '$group': {
        '_id': 0,
        'all-usr': {'$sum': '$ts.cpu-load-all.cpu.usr'}
    }
}])))
```

Comment: Does this store the result server-side as well? Or can I access the result of the query somehow?

Comment: When I `print list(...)` with your example above filled in, I get an empty list returned.

Comment: PyMongo's aggregate returns a cursor: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/examples/aggregation.html  To store the result on the server use the aggregation pipeline operator "$out": https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: Thanks! How could I modify your example to only consider `cpu-load-all.cpu[0].usr`? That is, if I only wanted the value of `usr` from the first `cpu[]` field?